# How to store data from URL in sqlite database iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite, urlloader

I have hosted web service(.Net) on IIS to get the data from SQL Server DB;parse it and store it in my SQlite DB in iPhone.How can i do this?

My web service is working fine and I'm getting data in XML format.

I searched on net, but did not found any suitable tutorial for this.Could any one please suggest any link or tutorial? Thanks.

Comment: What format is this *data*?

Comment: You can store it as a `text` or `blob` column then.